# Perl - Generate All Matching String To A Regex

Tags: regex, perl, data-generation

I am kinda new in perl, i wanted to know if there is a way for generating all the combinations that matches a regex.

how is the best way to generate all the matching strings to :

```
05[0,2,4,7][\d]{7}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: I agree with Kendall Frey's comment below, you are probably trying to do something the wrong way, so you should probably try to describe your main problem situation.

Comment: This is a frequently asked question. I downvoted this for lack of research. - Edit: and indeed, it has come up on SO before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208733/generative-regular-expressions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605289/listing-all-patterns-that-a-regex-matches

Comment: maybe you should learn something about regular languages and other stuff about formal grammatics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there is no way to generate all matches for a certain regex. Consider this one:

```
a+
```

There is an infinite number of matches for that regex, thus you cannot list them all.

By the way, I think you want your regex to look like this:

```
05[0247]\d{7}
```

Comment: Thanks,what is the efficient way of generating these strings?

Comment: You will need to use something other than a regex, since regexes are too flexible. Also, *there is no efficient way*. The best you can get is exponential time. I don't know what your problem is, but I'd guess there is a good chance you are doing it wrong.

Comment: there is no problem, i just want to generate all these number for testing purposes.

Answer (score 5):

While you cannot just take any regex and produce any strings it might fit, in this case you can easily adapt and overcome.

You can use [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) to generate combinations:

```
perl -lwe "print for glob '05{0,2,4,7}'"
050
052
054
057
```

However, I should not have to tell you that `\d{7}` actually means quite a few million combinations, right? Generating a list of numbers is trivial, formatting them can be done with [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html):

```
my @nums = map sprintf("%07d", $_), 0 .. 9_999_999;
```

That is assuming you are only looking for 0-9 numericals.

Take those nums and combine them with the globbed ones: Tada.

Answer (score 3):

## 2012 answer

- [String::Random](http://p3rl.org/String::Random)
- [Regexp::Genex](http://p3rl.org/Regexp::Genex) - generates random strings that match the regexp; not all the possible strings, even for finite patterns like `[class]`
- [Parse::RandGen](http://p3rl.org/Parse::RandGen)
- [§6.5 regex string generation](http://hop.perl.plover.com/book/pdf/06InfiniteStreams.pdf) in [HOP](http://hop.perl.plover.com/book/)

Answer (score 1):

Then there *is* a way to generate all (four billion of) the matches for this certain regex, viz., `05[0247]\d{7}`:

```
use Modern::Perl;

for my $x (qw{0 2 4 7}) {
    say "05$x" . sprintf '%07d', $_ for 0 .. 9999999;
}
```